# Не работает окошко alert() при внешнем подключении js файла

Tags: javascript, html, html5, alert

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь создать форму на странице сайта. С помощью js хотелось бы выдавать алерты типа "вы не заполнили имя" и т.д. Я на начальном этапе, пытаюсь ссылаться на функцию в js файле. Код javascript в папке javascript.js. Вставила везде ссылки на этот файл, и все никак. В чем проблема? Спасибо!:

```js
function valid() {
 var name = form.firstname.value;
 alert(name);
 
}
```

```html
<body id="recommendations">
     <script type = "text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>    
    <header class="header_subpages">
  <h1 class="page-title">Recommendations</h1>
        <nav>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
   <li><a href="recommendations.html">Recommendations</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
     </nav> 
           
 </header>

         <h2 class="description_pages">Restaurants, budget-friendly ingredients etc.</h2> 
 
         <div id="container">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>  
   <form action="" method="post" name="test" onsubmit='valid()'>
   <div class="personaldata">
    
    <div class="heading">
    <h2>Introduce yourself:</h2>
    </div>
   
    <h2 class="person">First name</h2>  
    
<input class="input" type="text" name="firstname" id = "txtNormal"> 
    <h2 class="person">Last name</h2> 
<input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" id = "txtNormal2">
   </div>
    
   <div class="personaldata">
    <div class="heading">
    <h2>What dietary habits you stick to?</h2>
    </div>
    
   <div id="inputContainer">
    <div class="b">
    <input  type="radio" name="diet" value="meatarian" id = "meat" for="meat" checked>Meatatarian </div>
    <div class="b">
    <input  type="radio" name="diet" value="vegetarian" id = "vegetar" for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</div>
    <div class="b">
    <input  type="radio" name="diet" value="vegan" id = "vegan" for="vegan" >Vegan</div>
   </div>
    
   </div> 
    
   <div class="personaldata">
    <div class="heading">
    <h2>Your recommendations:</h2>
    </div>
<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="20" id="txtArea"> </textarea>
    </div>
    
<div id="buttons">
  <div class="buttposition">
   <button class="but" onclick = "processForm()">Submit</button></div>
    
  <div class="buttposition" ><button class="but" onclick = "setToNull">Reset</button></div>
</div>    
    
    </form>
             <div id="output"></div>
        </div>
  
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Перенесите подключение js-файла в конец тега `body`, а еще лучше посмотреть, что у вас находится в консоли браузера.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin перенесла, не реагирует. В консоль выводит ошибку с WebSocket, скриншот добавлен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы совершенно правильно делаете, что начинаете с простейшего скрипта, который должен выполниться во время определенного события. Файл со скриптом надо, конечно, вставлять в страницу один раз.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="test" onsubmit='valid(this)'>

function valid(form) {
    var name = form.firstname.value;
    alert(name);
}
```